# SAS by processing in SQL, adding a counter

Tags: sql, sas

I often find myself adding a counter-type variable based on by-group processing in SAS. However, I need to be able to do this in SQL as well. Any ideas please?

```
data one;
  input col1 col2;
datalines;
101 1
101 2
101 2
;
run;

data two;
  retain counter;
  set one;
  by col1 col2;
  if first.col2 then counter = 0;
  counter + 1;
  if last.col2 then output;
run;
```

so, table TWO looks like this:

```
COL1 COL2 COUNTER
101  1    1
101  2    2
```

Comment: Do you need it to work in pure SAS code or are you connecting to some remote database where you could use explicit passthru to code using that database's implementation of SQL?  If the later then look into windowing functions. Most will have a row_number() function (or equivalent).

Comment: I'm actually needing to convert it to Redshift SQL code. Can do all the group by processing in SAS but adding the counter bit has eluded me so far. thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you only want to count by groups you can simply use count:

```
proc sql;
  create table two as
    select Count(*) as counter,col1,col2 from one group by col1,col2;
quit;
```

NOTE: The counter is the first war because it would also be the first in you equivalent datastep. Also note there is no sorting needed as sorting will be done implicit.

Answer (score 1):

Your `DATA` step for counting the number of records in a group can be recoded using a DOW loop

```
data two(keep=col1 col2 counter);
  do counter = 1 by 1 until (last.col2);
    set one;
    by col1 col2;
  end;
run;
```

A SQL result set has no implicit order unless there is an `ORDER BY` clause.  SQL does not have the concept of serial processing like the DATA step, in which a monotonic increasing sequence number can be assigned within a group.

When each record has enough satellite data to unconditionally position itself within the result set, an SQL join can compute a sequence number based on counts of 'triangular' comparisons of the satellite variable.  This is an expensive proposition compared to the +1 approach done in DATA step.

Example:

```
data have;
  call streaminit(1234);
  do col1 = 'Z', 'X', 'A';
    do col2 = 1 to 4 + rand('uniform', 10);
      do _n_ = 1 to 4 + rand('uniform', 10);
        col3 = ceil(rand('uniform', 1e7));  /* presume col3 is distinct within group and will order the rows within the group (col1,col2) */
        output;
      end;
    end;
  end;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want
  as select one.col1, one.col2, one.col3, count(*) as seq
  from have as one
  join have as two
    on one.col1=two.col1 and one.col2 = two.col2   /* group */
  where two.col3 <= one.col3                       /* col3 used for triangle criteria */
  group by one.col1, one.col2, one.col3
  order by one.col1, one.col2, seq
;
quit;
```